# Get an eventbrite event ID

Tags: eventbrite, event-id

I'm trying to figure out how to get an Eventbrite Event ID for an event that does not include it in the URL. I'm not the event owner, so I can't use the technique to go to my "manage events" page, like eventbrite tells me.

Also, I can't find a consistently good way to use the event search API method to find the specific event I want...

It seems as though this should be a pretty easy thing to do!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to grab an event ID (just a quick trick without using the API) is to look in the event's footer at "Contact the Organizer" -- opening that link in a new tab will display the EID in the URL.

For the problem around /event_search, try using keywords and narrowing the search with location parameters: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/

Hope that answers your questions!